# Office365 relay-POSTFIX-Authentication unsuccessful

Tags: postfix, microsoft-office-365

Having issues setting Office 365 as relay in postfix

```
yum install cyrus-sasl cyrus-sasl-plain cyrus-sasl-md5
```

sasl_passwd:

```
[smtp.office365.com]:587 user@xompany.com:password
```

main.cf:

```
relayhost = [smtp.office365.com]:587
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_generic_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/generic

smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
```

cat /etc/sasl2/smtpd.conf

pwcheck_method: saslauthd

mech_list: plain login

Error:

```
localhost postfix/smtp[6073]: 60B1E400E9F9: SASL authentication failed; server smtp.office365.com[40.101.77.82] said: 535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful [VI1PR07CA0165.eurprd07.prod.outlook.com]
```

what am i missing ? I see in some guides SSL certificates are used, if it's a must, what's procedure to obtain them ?

Comment: !!!! THIS IS SOLUTION !!!!!! mods keep delete my way how so solve this : Open the Microsoft 365 admin center and go to Users > Active users. Select the user, and in the flyout that appears, click Mail.  In the Email apps section, click Manage email apps. Verify the Authenticated SMTP setting: unchecked = disabled, checked = enabled. When you're finished, click Save changes.

Answer (score 2):

In our case it was the "Azure Security defaults" in https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_IAM/ActiveDirectoryMenuBlade/Properties:

Security Defaults enabled:

*SASL authentication failed; server smtp.office365.com[x.y.z.a] said: 535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful*

Security Defaults disabled (20min later):

*relay=smtp.office365.com[x.y.z.a]:587, delay=17, delays=0.03/0.03/17/0.37, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK*

We are looking into the security setting exactly preventing SASL Auth.

EDIT: Without "Azure AD Premium" it is only possible to enable/disable AD security Defaults. With default settings, SMTP_Auth is legazy and not supported anymore. I still do not understand why SMTP_Auth is considered legacy

Some Background Information:
https://practical365.com/azure-ad/what-are-azure-ad-security-defaults-and-should-you-use-them/

Comment: This actually helped me solve a completely unrelated SMTP Auth issue in my O365 tenant, so thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Got it working, i missed one letter in username, once corrected it ran `postmap hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd`,restarted postfix and messages started to flow